# Spring MVC (Hibernate+Maven) - Multiple Controllers and Sessions (Login/Logouts)

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-mvc, web-applications, spring-security

I am working on a mid size project using Spring MVC, Hibernate and Maven.

My application has a Login page, which authenticates users and then routes to Main page which has a menu. From the menu, user can go to multiple menu options. Application is divided into multiple modules - employees, payroll, absence management etc.

Fairly new on this platform and have few questions.

1. Controllers: Shall I use a single controller for entire application OR use multiple controllers?
2. If I should use multiple - should it be one controller for Login module and one for each module such as employee, payroll, etc.? How can I make them talk to each other and pass control?

   What should be the return value of the method marked with @RequestMapping? If i just give the return value as 'return "Employee"' and i do have an Employee.jsp in my views, but the Employee related things are in EmployeeController, how do i make sure my code isnt still stuck in the previous controller (for example LoginController)?

   Do I need to create a Master Controller to manage all these controllers?
3. In order to retain the user credentials across all the pages, I will have to use session object in Login module? Or will Spring MVC handle that by default?

I found few relevant pages. They are good, but they explain very simple scenarios and were not useful for my actual problem.

Will appreciate your help on above questions.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to answer this is to treat a controller just like any other piece of code you'd write.  When we design classes, we do so adhering to:

- Single Responsibility Principal
- Separation of Concerns

It is typically acceptable to create a controller that accepts several URI end-points that manipulate a particular model for CRUD operations, since those end-points often accept identical or nearly identical types of input.  But to create a controller for differing models or an entire application to me violates the two points above; however, your entitled to your opinion :).

To understand controller communication, you need to understand how HTTP works in a general sense.  A web application is nothing more than a fancy way to design a request-response system.  You tell your browser to go to a particular URL and it sends that request to a server.  The server interprets your request, manipulates local server-side state perhaps, queries a data store if applicable, and finally replies with a response.  That response could be static or dynamic in nature.  The dynamic response could be forwarded to a view technology to render the final content you receive.  Those view technologies can also be server-side like JSP/JSF or client-side like Angular.

Spring MVC controllers talk with each through through view orchestrated navigation.  When you put a button, form, or a link on your web page, that represents a navigation path to transition from that page to another page.  In action-based frameworks like Spring MVC, that typically means that you transition to that new page by sending your request to another controller that parses the request, perhaps some action, and finally passes state to the view.

There is no need for a *master* controller but rather an understanding of the type of controller you are dealing with.  Before the Web 2.0 revolution and AJAX, we had just a single type of controller that was meant to handle transitioning a user from one view to another.  Today with AJAX and dynamic content being mainstream, you'll often have another type of controller that has the sole purpose of being a data-provider.  It isn't necessarily meant to *transition* from one view to another as much as it is meant to render partial page dynamic content based on some input.

So taking an example

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
  @RequestMapping("/employee/view")
  public String viewEmployee(@RequestParam("id") Integer id, Model model) {
    // lookup the employee by the passed "?id=123" 123 value
    final Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployee( id );

    // set the employee in the model so I can render it in JSP
    model.addAttribute( "employee", employee );

    // return the name of what view to display
    return "view";
  }
}
```

This code shown here wouldn't be stuck in a "prior" controller because a user would need to submit a form or click a link or a button to submit a request to the server like `/employee/view?id=123` in order for that controller to do it's work.

And finally, yes a `HttpSession` object is necessary to track state across multiple requests.  An `HttpRequest` is a short-lived object of which there are tens to hundreds of them performed by a single user throughout the lifetime of their `HttpSession`.

In the spring-world, you often have Spring Security configured to handle authentication.  In this case, that library will maintain a relationship between a `SESSIONID` and a user's authentication so that on each `HttpRequest`, it knows whether the user has been authenticated, redirecting them to login if not or allowing their request to invoke the controller if it has.

Comment: Thank you Naros for setting me in the right direction. :)
I have started working on this further, will let you know in case I have any additional queries.